# How can I download only the data selected from plotly dropdown? (instead of the whole dataset?

Tags: callback, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I plotted a plotly graph using dcc.graph based on multiple dropdowns. Now, I'm trying to download the data used in the graph as a csv. file. I'm able to download the complete datafile using dcc.download but I was wondering if there is a method to only download the rows which match the dropdown filters.

This is my current code. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
html.Button('Download', id='btn', n_clicks=0),
html.Div([
html.Div(children= dcc.Download(id="download-component"), className = "download_btn"),
],className = "wrapper"
),

@app.callback(
    Output("download-component", "data"),
   [Input("btn", "n_clicks"),
   Input("seg-filter", "value"),
   Input("freq-filter", "value"),],
   prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def download_csv(seg_nm, freq_typ, n_clicks):
     n_clicks = 0
    filtered_data2 = df2[(df2.SEG_TYP == seg_nm) & (df2.FREQ_TYP == freq_typ)]
    filtered_data_2 = filtered_data2.sort_values(by='DATE')
    return dcc.send_data_frame(filtered_data_2.to_csv, "dfcsv.csv")
```

Comment: Only the "btn" component triggers the callback if I understand correctly, so you should have only one Input() for that button, for the two filters you need to use State() instead of Input().